# AngularJS show url or plain text if value contain text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I show in AngularJS and url or a plain text if a variable contains text?

For example let's have the model

```
$scope.model = {
   Url: ''       
};


<div data-ng-controller="myController">
  if (model.Url)
  {
    <a href="{{model.Url}}">URL</a>
  }
  else
  {
     <p>{{model.Url}}</p>
  }

<div>
```

P.S. The if else condition is for demo purpose, so how can I acheieve that using a directive like `data-ng-if` ?

Comment: If your `if` statement resolves to false, then there is nothing to display in the `p` tag anyway...

Comment: You don't specify the conditions in your example. Besides that wouldn't it be confusing if property named Url contained something else besides URL or null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController">
  <a ng-if="model.Url" ng-href="{{model.Url}}">URL</a>
  <p ng-if="!model.Url">{{model.Url}}</p>
<div>
```

**Note:** you should use `ng-href` instead of `href` otherwise browser doesn't update attribute.

**Update**

This thing works only if url present or empty as in provided example. It doesn't check is value url or text. See answer below that checks.

Comment: This just wraps same flawed logic using different angular directives?

Comment: I agree with @MikkoViitala, this is just checks if model.url has a value, not whether it is a url or not.

Comment: Yes, guys. Sorry, I misread the question. This thing works only if url present or empty, that's true, but exactly as in provided example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to test if a block of text is a URL or not

```
$scope.isURL = function(text){
    var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
    // alternative
    // var expression = new RegExp("^(http[s]?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|ftp:\\/\\/(www\\.)?|www\\.){1}([0-9A-Za-z-\\.@:%_\+~#=]+)+((\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})+)(/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)?");

    var regex = new RegExp(expression);
    /// for example text could be: text = 'www.google.com';
    if (text.match(regex) ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController">

    <div ng-init="model.url = 'some text'"></div>

    <div ng-if="isURL(model.url)"> 
         <a ng-href='model.url' > is url </a>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="!isURL(model.url)"> 
         <p ng-bind='model.url' > </p>
    </div>

    <!-- better done as ng-switch -->
    <div ng-switch on="isURL(model.url)"> 
        <p ng-switch-when='false' ng-bind='model.url'></p>
        <a ng-switch-when='true' ng-href='model.url' ng-bind='model.url'></a>
    </div>

<div>
```

Comment: This is the template for a directive. This just needs to be copy/pasted into a directive and it will work. It contains all the necessary logic. This forum is not for doing work for other people, but for helping them with their coding problems.